# spotify api playlist_tracks() limits

Tags: python, api, spotify, spotipy

I use Python and Spotipy lib.
Is there any way to list **all** songs from spotify playlist? 
Method playlist_tracks() has limit to print only 100 songs.
Same question about other methods eg. current_user_saved_tracks() with its 20 limits.
Why spotify api have these limits?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to get all songs in a playlist you use the first request to determine the total song count which is part of the spotify response.
Dividing the total count by the max song limit per request (100) and rounding up the result will give you the necessary amount of api calls needed to get all song.

With this information in mind you simply loop from 0 to call count and request the next 100 song.
Inside the loop you have to set the offset property of the request to x * 100.
Furthermore your have to add the requested songs to a temporary array to get the entire list at the end.

I can only assume that the general limit of 100 songs per request is a technical need at spotify.

Comment: I thought there is a simplier way but thanks anyway :)